# How do we create this algebraic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given a pair of $2$ values such that:

$v_0=a^2+1-a$

$v_1=a^2 \cdot (1-a)$

where, $0\leq a<1$.

How do we create a single algebraic equation that recovers the value of $a$.

Moreover, when $a=0$ i.e. $v_0=1, v_1=0$ the equation must have exactly 1 solution $a=0$. Or, if it makes things simpler the solution can alternatively be $a=1$. But not both.

We can only use the algebraic and if needed trigonometric identities. I don't want to use any special logical operations or operations that require some internal logic (for example: comparison for $<, >, =$, modulus($x$) etc). We do howsoever have access to one special function: Abs($x$) - return absolute value of $x$. (when $-180<x<180$, so it works fine for our case)

We can easily solve both equations seperately and compare the roots of each to find the one that satisfies both, but the objective is to have a single equation without need of any comparison or logical operation whatsoever.

Been struggling with this for a while but not much progress. Can anyone please help?

Comment: The first equation has no solutions when $v_0 < \frac{3}{4}$; exactly one when $v_0 = \frac{3}{4}$ and two when it's bigger than that.

Comment: Actually, what is the difference between your Abs(x), which you allow, and modulus(x), which you don't?

Comment: $abs()$ gives abslute value of input. $abs(-x)=abs(+x)=x$. What I mean by modlus is the residue after division function, eg: $x\%1$ gives the decimal part of $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Note there is no way to distinguish $a=0$ and $a=1$ just from the values of $v_0,v_1$ (as both cases give $v_0=1$ and $v_1=0$).

If $a$ is constrained to $0<a<1$ (so $v_0\neq 1$ and $v_1\neq 0$), then we have $v_1=a\cdot a\cdot(1-a)=a\cdot(1-v_0)$ so we can recover $a$ by
$$
a=\frac{v_1}{1-v_0}.
$$
If you are doing it on finite-precision floating point machines, then from $v_0\in[\frac34,1]$ you can estimate how many terms you need from
$$
\frac1{1-v_0}=1+v_0+v_0^2+v_0^3+\dots
$$
and get
$$
a=v_1\cdot(1+v_0+v_0^2+\dots+v_0^{N(v_0)})
$$
which does not require special function, and has the benefit of returning $a=0$ when $v_1=0$.

---

Alternatively, we can use the quadratic formula on the $v_0$ equation and decide which sign to choose based on the sign of $2v_1+v_0-1$.  The $\operatorname{sgn}x=\frac{x}{\lvert x\rvert}$ obviously has a problem if $x=0$ ($a=0,\frac12,1$) so you need to work around that.

Comment: Thank you. As I undertand the first equation addreses all but not the cases a=0 and a=1. The second does that but for only $v_0 \leq e/4$. Can we modify either of these to get a single equation that handle the boundary cases as well in the sense that for both a=0, a=1 it returns 0? The reason I need a single equantion is I am working on 2 series that outputs $v_0$ and $v_1$ and another that requires $a$ from it. The series is infinite   and $v_0$ takes on all values including 0, and I intend to do a subtitution if I can find a expression for a using $v_0$ and $v_1$.

Comment: $a=1$ doesn't matter so I should rather have said $0\leq a < 1$. so for $v_0=1$ a can have only a single value $a=0$. Can we alter any of the equations to handle this case as well ?

Comment: To be honest I don't understand your aversion to using logic in the one exceptional case.  The penalty is nowhere near the huge effort you need to put in to go around the mathematical constraint that $v_0,v_1$ are not local parameter at $a=0,\frac12$.

Comment: If I intend to solve an equation and get the value of $a$ based on $v_0$ and $v_1$ and insert/substitute $a$ in another equation I can't substitute the logical if else etc. in a mathematical series/equation to be solved..

Comment: You can always use $a=a(v_0,v_1)$.

Comment: I have to integrate the resulting infinte series.. I am not sure how will I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little troubled that $a$ can take the value of zero, however, constraining this to $0<a\leq1$

\begin{align}
v_0 &= a^2+1-a \qquad \tag{1}\\
v_1 &= a^2(1-a) \qquad \tag{2}
\end{align}
From $(2)$ write into $(1)$ as
\begin{align}v_0 &= a^2+1-a \\ 
&= a^2 +\frac{v_1}{a^2}\\
\implies a^2v_0&=a^4+v_1\\
\implies 0 &=a^4-v_0 a^2+v_1
\end{align}
quadratic in, say, $u=a^2$ from which
$$a=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{v_0\pm\sqrt{v_0^2-4v_1}}$$

Is this what you were hoping to show?

Comment: The 0 is the boundary case we will have to adress eventually. But, ignoring that for the time being: Let $a=.1$. Thus, given $v_0=.91$ and $v_1=.009$. The cubic equation has roots $.1, .99083, -.09083$ and the quadratic equation has roots $.1, .9$. The common value that satisfies both is $.1$. We are aiming at a single equation that takes $v_0$ and $v_1$ as inputs and when solved has a single answer $a=.1$. The aim is to combine both equations into a single one.

Comment: if possible can you please comment? we want a single output as i commented above. not set of all possible roots. another answer above helps but fails for case a=1. thats where i am stuck at

Comment: Must be $v_0^2-4v_1$ instead of $v_0^2-v_1^2$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Yes, quite right. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $a^2$ and $1-a$ are solutions of $x^2-v_0x+v_1=0$.

Comment: thanks. See I understand the way to find all the roots. That is not the issue. What I am struggling with is the way to form an equation that finds the value of $a$ that was used in $v_0$ and $v_1$. In fact even that also seems possible [above answer: $a=\frac{v_1}{1-v_0}.$] but the boundary case is what I am really struggling with for days. It has to give a single answer for the boundary case too, where this equation fails. And I am still lost here :(